# Using the Me object

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

```
MustInherit Class Person
    Overridable Function TableName() As String
        Return "Person"
    End Function
    Sub Save
        DoSomething(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Staff
    Inherits Person
    Overrides Function TableName() As String
        Return "Staff"
    End Function
    Overloads Sub Save()
        MyBase.Save()
        DoSomething(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
Sub DoSomething(o as Object)
    DoAnotherThing(o.TableName)
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can get Me in DoSomething to refer to Person in Person.Save and Staff in Staff.Save? At the moment they both refer to the Staff instance.

I am trying to write a general routine to save properties to a database, the (inherited - not my code) problem is there are 3 objects inheriting Person (Staff, Clients, Contacts) and tons of almost-duplicated code, which makes 4 database tables (Person has data common to the 3).

Comment: There is only one `Me`, but there are different properties under `Me.` and `MyClass.`. If you could modify `DoSomething(o as Object)` to `DoSomething(o as String)`, you could pass `DoSomething(MyClass.TableName)` in both classes, and that would pass two different things for `Staff`.

Comment: @GSerg, I am using the object for other things e.g. using Reflection to get a list of properties and write them to the database as well. It would be nice to wrap them all up in something (like an object :) ). There's a thought, maybe Reflection can help.

Comment: Ultimately the type of the object to query on is decided in `DoSomething`, and because it's `o as Object`, it queries the most derived type each time, so even though you are trying to use non-virtual methods to achieve your goal, which would be correct, it has no effect. If you could have two `DoSomething`s, one `o As Person` and another `o As Staff`, it would work like you imagine. You would only have to fix your inheritance - `TableName` mustn't be virtual, and `Save` may or may not, it doesn't matter.

Comment: `Me` will always refer to the current instance as itself.  If you want access to the base class instead, use `MyBase`.  Incidentally, `Overloads` looks like it's wrong on the derived class, since it doesn't change the argument list.  It should be `Shadows` instead.

Comment: For something like `Save`, I would think that a more typical way to do it would be to have it be `Overridable` in the parent with an implementation for the parent aspects, then the child classes would use `Overrides`, provide their piece, and call back to the parent using `MyBase.Save` (either before or after doing their own piece).  Note that the Visual Studio editor will automatically insert the `MyBase.Save` call if you use the IntelliSense override completion.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this structure would help

```
MustInherit Class BasePersons
    'stuff common to classes that Inherit here
    MustOverride Function TableName() As String

    MustOverride Sub Save()

    Sub DoSomething(BP As BasePersons)
        'code
        Debug.WriteLine(BP.TableName)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Person
    Inherits BasePersons

    Overrides Function TableName() As String
        Return "Person"
    End Function

    Overrides Sub Save()
        DoSomething(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Staff
    Inherits BasePersons

    Overrides Function TableName() As String
        Return "Staff"
    End Function

    Overrides Sub Save()
        DoSomething(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: twas not me. As I said in another comment, I am using the object for more than just TableName.

Comment: Is a comment really needed? The OP has four object types that save into four tables, each into two. `Staff` needs to save to tables `Person` and `Staff`. So `Staff`'s `Save` attempts to call `DoSomething` both "as Person" and "as Staff", to trigger saving into both. This answer has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only applies to one object, I just redefined a couple of subs

```
Sub DoSomething(o as Object, optional IsPerson as Boolean = false)
    Dim TableName As String = If(IsPerson, "Person", obj.TableName)        
    DoAnotherThing(o, TableName)
End Sub

Sub DoAnotherThing(o as Object, TableName as string)
```

Hacky, not at all OO, but good enough for me.